# Apply SVN patch to GIt repo

Tags: git, svn

I have a patch file which I have generated via "`svn diff`" command from one of my svn repository.

Now, I have moved the repository to github and I need to apply that patch file to my git repository. 
The problem is that each time I try to apply the patch to my GIT repo, all the patch hunks get failed.

I have already tried via "`git apply`" and "`patch`" commands but none of them seemed to work correctly.

Note: I know this question has already been asked before but none of the provided answers seems to be working for me, so just trying out my luck here.

Comment: Have you looked at the rejects to try and work out where the problem is happening?

Comment: It fails by saying: No such file exists. So it has to do something with the path but the paths seems to be fine.

Comment: Perhaps post the actual commands you tried and at least the first few lines of the patch

Comment: **Which options** you used in `svn diff`? The same patch can't be used for both `git apply` and `patch`

Comment: I got diff just by running command: "svn diff > patchfile.diff"

Answer (score 5):

If you're applying a diff from Subversion to git, you should be using [`svn diff --git`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.git) to produce git's preferred format.